# Access Siblings by Sender

Tags: vb.net, siblings, sender

I have two tabs in a tab control which basically have the same controls. Here's an example in which both tabs have in common:

GroupBox

- DataGridView
- Button1
- Button2

On my click event of Button2 I want to access it's sibling (DataGridView) via the sender.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tab1_Button2.Click, Tab2_Button2.Click
    Dim currSender As Button = sender
```

Do I need to go through the "currSender" parent? I'm not sure how to access those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = currSender.Parent.Controls("DataGridView1")
```

Thats using the name of the control. You can get all the `Datagridview`'s on the GroupBox and take the (I suppose) first and only one:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = crrSender.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)(0)
```

Comment: Almost, here's what I used
Dim currSender As Button = sender
        Dim siblings As DataGridView = currSender.Parent.Controls.Item(2)

Comment: @Alex That sigthly more dangerous, because the order of the controls may vary, and you depend on it.

Comment: you're right, I tried using the second portion of your code but it doesn't let me because of too many arguements. It won't let me enter in the (0) as an index of getting the first datagridview.